# How can you limit an iOS device to a certain volume level when headphones are initially connected?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, headphones

My car has an aux input, so I have to turn the volume up all the way on my iPhone in order to get the most out of the car's speakers. When I get home and plug in my headphones, there's potential for it to actually hurt my ears if I forget to turn down the volume before hitting play, or if it's already playing and I plug in my headphones. It's happened way too many times. Both my ears and my headphones have probably been damaged to some extent by it over the years.

The solution is obvious - an option to limit the maximum output when any new audio device connects (ideally with overrides for different devices). I couldn't find it in Settings (WTF?), but it should be in there. If not, maybe it's possible with Shortcuts?

Comment: You can limit the output, but not by device. The phone doesn't know what it's connected to, it's just a socket you put a plug in, there's no transference of data.

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't need to know the device, all it needs to know is that it's the headphone jack (which it obviously does).  Whenever a pair of headphones are first plugged in, it should assess a max start volume setting for the headphone jack. By "overrides for different devices" I meant an override for each bluetooth device + an override for the headphone jack, in case you don't want a bluetooth device to adhere to the same limit you set for the headphone jack.

Comment: You never mentioned bluetooth, you said 'aux input' which by definition is wired.